# Puton alternative for PouchDB available? (Futon - CouchDB equivalent)

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-futon, nosql

CouchDB has the amazing Futon interface, which makes working with the database really easy.

For PouchDB there was the equivalent Puton (http://puton.jit.su/), which aimed to provide similar functionality. The problem is, it doesn't work for me, and looking at the code on Github, this project seems dead (last commit over a year ago).

Is there any other alternative to visually browser the PouchDB database? I haven't found anything and it seems like not a lot of people are actually using it.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding a solution here so people can find it later.

Setting up a CouchDB locally (cloud works as well, though) and doing a 2 way sync with db.sync or db.replicate in both ways works very well.

So just do some stuff in your app which writes to PouchDB, and then you can inspect it in Futon interface for CouchDB. Be sure to set continuous: true and you'll be fine. You will have an instant representation of your data, using the great Futon.

Hope that helps someone later.

Answer (score 0):

There is [pouchdb-fauxton](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-fauxton-logic), which is a version of CouchDB Fauxton that works directly on top of PouchDB by intercepting HTTP calls and translating them into PouchDB calls -- so it is not a port.

I'm not sure how to make it work exactly, but it seems to need [this other package](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-fauxton-base) and some file manipulation.

However, [it's beautiful](https://ma.rtendevri.es/fauxton/).